# Error Using SqlCeCommandBuilder while inserting row with column identity turned on

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I am trying to use the SqlCeCommandBuilder, and I am having an issue with it. My table, I am using has three columns. The first is set to primary key, and identity is on and set to increment by one. When I am creating my SqlCeCommand, I cannot get it to execute. I thought if I leave that column out, it will automatically add the value, but it returns an error stating the number of columns in the command have to match the number of columns in the table. So if I add the "BillerID" column to the command builder, it says I need to add a value for it. Then when I add a value, it says that the column "BillerID" cannot be modified.  What am I doing wrong?

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BillsConnectionStringDefault))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
                "INSERT INTO Billers VALUES(@BillerID, @Name, @Type)", con))
                {
                                       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("BillerID", 999999));                      
                   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("Name", billerName));
                   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("Type", "0"));
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {                   
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(ex.Message.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the columns you're inserting into, try changing the query to this:

```
"INSERT INTO Billers (Name, Type) VALUES(@Name, @Type)"
```

and leaving out the ID parameter entirely.

Comment: Awesome! I do not know why I didn't try it that way. It worked perfectly. I don't know why, on top of all of the other methods I tried, this change didn't cross my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! Can you click the tick-mark to mark it as the answer?